# MATPLOT PSD (Power Density Spectrale)

Tags: python, matplotlib, gnuradio

I woudlike to do an PSD (base on Welch's average) of my sdr module in python. 
I use this function :

```
matplotlib.mlab.psd(x, NFFT=None, Fs=None, detrend=None, window=None, noverlap=None, pad_to=None, sides=None, scale_by_freq=None)
```

[Source](https://matplotlib.org/api/mlab_api.html)

Actually my problem is about how to choose the gap between each value ?

For example, I want to have 10 values between 105 and 106. So I'll have 10 values like this :

`105.1, 105.2 105.3 105.4 105.5 105.6 105.7 105.8 105.9 106`

Acutally I did this :

```
psd(samples, NFFT=10, Fs=sdr.sample_rate/1e6, Fc=sdr.center_freq)
```

My radio module have 1.024 MHz sample rate but the gap between each value is not regular like this : `Fc=105.3 ===>  105.300001  105.300003.....`

Source: https://github.com/roger-/pyrtlsdr

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`mlab.psd()` uses an algorithm that does not handle irregularly spaced time intervals. You could either round or interpolate to evenly spaced time points. Have a look at [this answer](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/596) about dealing with this problem.

Comment: oh ok, so they have no solution from this function to handle irregularly spaced time intervals. Maybe it exsit another FFT function to do that ?

Comment: If I want to keep using PSD. It better to round or interpolate ?